# Is there some kind of right distributivity of the subset predicate over set union?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

$X \cup Y \subset Z \leftrightarrow X \subset Z \wedge Y \subset Z$. Is there a similar simple rule for $X \subset Y \cup Z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that

$$X \subseteq Y \cap Z \quad \implies \quad X \subseteq Y \land X \subseteq Z.$$

What you would like is perhaps

$$X \subseteq Y \cup Z \quad \implies \quad X \subseteq Y \lor X \subseteq Z. \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

However, in general it does *not* work. Observe that it is similar to a definition of prime numbers:

$$ p \text{ is prime } \quad \iff\quad p \mid ab\ \text{ implies }\ p \mid a \lor p \mid b.$$

We know that there are numbers which are not prime, like $6$, 
$$6 \mid 2\cdot3 \quad \implies\hspace{-15pt}\not{}\hspace{15pt} \quad 6 \mid 2 \lor 6 \mid 3.$$ Similarly 
$$\{2,3\} \subseteq \{2\} \cup \{3\} \quad \implies\hspace{-15pt}\not{}\hspace{15pt} \quad
\{2,3\} \subseteq \{2\} \lor \{2,3\}\subseteq\{3\}.$$

The key is the fact that prime numbers cannot be split, while composite numbers can. In other words $(\spadesuit)$ is true for any $X$ that cannot be partitioned, i.e. a singleton or the empty set.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

No, but there is such a rule for intersection: $X\subseteq Y\cap Z$ if and only if $X\subseteq Y$ and $X\subseteq Z$.

Comment: I guess I'll have to settle.

Comment: @user143882: note that $\{1,2\}\subseteq\{1\}\cup\{2\}$.